# SED-POSIX-specified -E option inside script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a tricky question.

I have this .sed script where I need to do some stuff and then execute all the lines of the script with "**sed -f script.sed filename.csv**"

Inside the script I have used a **regexp expression** and if when executing the script I use **-E**, the script works. (sed **-E** -f script.sed filename.csv)

BUT, the thing is, I CANNOT used it, so in the terminal I need to execute the script like this "**sed -f script.sed filename.csv**"

***Then, the question is, Is there a human possible way to make a regexp expression WORK inside a SCRIPT without using -E in the terminal? Can it be included INSIDE the SCRIPT somehow?***

I will write down the script to give more context:

```
s/ESP/Spain/g  #this line changes ESP for Spain in all rows

s/DEN/Denmark/g  #this line changes DEN for Denmark in all rows

s/NED/Netherlands/g  #this line changes NED for Netherlands in all rows

s/^([^,]*,)([^,]+)((,[^,]*){5},(shooting|judo),)/\1\U\2\L\3/  #This line, changes to UPPER CASE all names of athletes that have as sport either judo or shooting. This is the line that does not work without the -E in the terminal.

/[0],[0],[0],$/d  #This line deletes all rows where the last 3 columns have these values

1 c id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info   #this line makes the header not upper case
```

If you need some data to work with, there you have it:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
388896171,Abdelraouf Benguit,ALG,male,1985-07-03,1.83,90,judo,0,0,0,
285603057,Abderrahmane Mansouri,ALG,male,1995-01-13,1.72,66,cycling,0,0,0,
545134894,Abderrahmane Meziane,ALG,male,1994-03-07,1.68,62,football,0,0,0,
969824503,Abdullah Alrashidi,IOA,male,1963-08-21,1.83,84,shooting,0,0,1,
897549624,Abdullah Hel Baki,BAN,male,1989-08-01,,,shooting,0,0,0,
153457,Abdullahi Shehu,NGR,male,1993-03-12,1.70,,football,0,0,1,
```

This is part of a file named athletesv2.csv

Please don't ask why I can't use it, but I'm forbiden from using this option.

BR,

Comment: If you stick to BRE syntax then yes you can

Comment: How would it be line nº4 in BRE instead of ERE? I new to this and not used to change from BRE to ERE and the other way

Comment: Inside the script? On top of it? Yes, I tried but nothing.

Comment: The 4th command as POSIX BRE can look like `s/^\([^,]*,\)\([^,]\+\)\(\(,[^,]*\)\{5\},\(shooting\|judo\),\)/\1\U\2\L\3/` and will only work with GNU sed

Comment: Now I don't get the error but the name column is not changing to upper case. So it's not following the condition. I have just changed the line but the execution is the same "sed -f ......."

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot a  \. Please Wiktor, if you can put your code as answer I will give the credit to you :). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the first three commands as is:

```
s/ESP/Spain/g  #this line changes ESP for Spain in all rows
s/DEN/Denmark/g  #this line changes DEN for Denmark in all rows
s/NED/Netherlands/g  #this line changes NED for Netherlands in all rows
```

The fourth command should be "converted" to POSIX BRE:

```
s/^\([^,]*,\)\([^,]\+\)\(\(,[^,]*\)\{5\},\(shooting\|judo\),\)/\1\U\2\L\3/
```

Note that this syntax is only supported by GNU `sed` (the `\|` as an alternation operator and `\+` as *one or more* quantifier are GNU extensions).